# Kubernetes on GKE: bind load balancer to specific ip

Tags: kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine

In gke one can define a load balancer and it will bind to the public ip of one of the node. How can I guaranty the service is always bound to the same public ip to not have to re configure external dns?

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the ClusterIP field when defining your service. The documentation for the field says "If specified, it will be allocated to the service if it is unused or else creation of the service will fail" so this should allow you to bind your service to a specific IP address (presuming that you are allowed to use that address).

Comment: tried that before but always get: 
invalid:spec.clusterIP: invalid value 'XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX': provided IP is not in the valid range

Comment: Hmm, it looks like the ClusterIP may be the IP you are requesting from the *internal* service ip range rather than an external IP. Can you try passing an IP in your service CIDR and see if that is accepted. If so, the documentation should be updated to make it clearer (and I'll see if I can dig up an actual answer).

Answer (score 0):

I don't think the LoadBalancer should be exposed through the IP of your pods, but instead get its own IP.

Use the Google cloud dashboard. Navigate to Networking › External IP addresses.

Find the IP of your LoadBalancer, and change it from ephemeral to static.